# RXJS combine sort and pagination streams

Tags: typescript, sorting, pagination, rxjs, reactive

So I have been learning RXJS but struggling a bit with this one. I have a pagination stream emitting which is calling `next` on `behaviorSubject` initialised with a default query, starting another stream.

This all works great and paginated results are concatenated from `scan` which is the desired result as pagination coming from infinite scroll.

Now i need to add sort stream, where page should be reset to 0 and items should not be appended to existing, which currently achieving through `scan`. I cannot add a filter. How can I achieve this?

```
    const items$ = this.queryChange$.pipe(
      switchMap((input: ItemQueryInput) => this.getAll$(input)),
    );

    const loadMoreItems$ = items$.pipe(
      scan<any>((acc, src) => acc.concat(src)),
      share(),
      tap((items) => console.warn('paginated', items)),
    );

    this.itemsRefresh$$ = loadMoreItems$.pipe(
      tap(items => {
        this.data = items;
        this.pageOffset = Math.ceil(items.length / LIMIT) + 1);
      })
    ).subscribe();

   private onPageNumberChange(pageNumber: number) {
    const query = _.merge({}, DEFAULT_QUERY, {
      pageOffset,
      sortBy: this.sortBy,
    } as ItemQueryInput);

    this.queryChange$.next(query);
  }

   private onSortChange(sort: SortEvent) {
    const { active, direction } = sort;
    const sortBy = this.sortBy = !_.isEmpty(direction) ? { field: active, order: direction } : null;
    const query = _.merge({}, DEFAULT_QUERY, {
      sortBy,
    } as ItemQueryInput);

    this.sortEvent$.next(true);
    this.queryChange$.next(query);
  }
```

In attempt to do was described above and your comments, I tried to use `filter` so that it only emits if sort is passed in query input.

However, the result is still the same, paginating works until `sort` is set. Upon sorting, items are updated, but pagination does not trigger anymore. Can't figure out why.

[EDIT]

```
    const paginatedItems$ = this.queryChange$.pipe(
      tap((query) => console.warn('paginated filter condition', _.isNil(query.sortBy) || query.pageOffset !== 1)),
      filter((query) => _.isNil(query.sortBy) || query.pageOffset !== 1),
      switchMap((query) => this.getAll$(query)),
      scan<any>((acc, src) => acc.concat(src)),
      tap((items) => this.pageOffset = _.round((items.length / LIMIT) + 1)),
      tap((items) => console.warn('paginated items, next pageoffset', items, this.pageOffset)),
    );

    const sortedItems$ = this.queryChange$.pipe(
      tap((query) => console.warn('sorted filter condition', !_.isNil(query.sortBy) || query.pageOffset === 1)),
      filter((query) => !_.isNil(query.sortBy) && query.pageOffset === 1),
      switchMap((query) => this.getAll$(query)),
      tap(() => this.pageOffset = 1),
      tap((items) => console.warn('sorted items, next pageOffset', items, this.pageOffset)),
    );

    const loadMoreItems$ = merge(paginatedItems$, sortedItems$).pipe(
      tap((items) => console.warn('loadedItems', items)),
    );

    this.loadMoreItems$$ = loadMoreItems$.pipe(
      tap(books => this.data = items)
    ).subscribe();
```

**More information**

Desired behaviour:

- accumulate results when pageOffset change (to behave as infinite scroll)
- replace results when sort change (and reset pageOffset), and can start paginating again from new.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand entirely what you mean but you should look into `combineLatest`, `withLatestFrom` and `filter` operator from `rxjs`.

Comment: You can not add filter where exactly?

Comment: @martin by using filter here, Im afraid I still get the same undesired behaviour.